# javascript comparison operator not evaluating user input correctly

Tags: javascript

Disclaimer: I'm an idiot.

This is extremely simple. I must be doing something very basic wrong, but I've spent a ton of time trying to figure it out, and I'm stumped.

For reference, The Entire Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Not comparing correctly</title>
</head>
<script>

//This is the main function. It creates a new game and plays it.
function playTheGame() {
    "use strict";
    //create the game object
    var currentGame = new game();
    //play the game
    currentGame.play(document.getElementById("eCurrentStake").value, document.getElementById("eGoalAmount").value);
}

// This is the game object.
function game(){
    //properties
    this.goalAmount = 0;
    this.currentStake = 0;

    //Play method Plays the game and stores the results in properties
    this.play=play;
    function play(currentStake,goalAmount){
        //set the relevant properties to values passed to the object
        this.goalAmount = goalAmount;
        this.currentStake = currentStake;
        alert(this.currentStake+" < "+this.goalAmount+" :"+(this.currentStake < this.goalAmount));
    };
}
</script>

<body>
    Enter Current Stake: <input type="text" id="eCurrentStake"></input><br>
    Enter Goal Amount: <input type="text" id="eGoalAmount"></input><br>

    <button type="button" onclick="playTheGame()">Let's Play!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The part of the code that's giving me trouble:

```
alert(this.currentStake+" < "+this.goalAmount+" :"+(this.currentStake < this.goalAmount));
```

When I put 9 and 10 into the input text fields, I get a, "false," output.
but 10 and 50 does return true. In short: the result is unpredictable. I think it might be evaluating as a string, but when I researched it, all I can find is that Javascript has dynamic data types and will compare variables as numbers if they are numbers. ie :

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

So, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You can nest functions with javascript??? wtf?

Comment: @progenhard: Yes, you can.  Learn about closures.

Comment: @SLaks I've never done work with javascript so it's an entire field i need to learn about <.<

Comment: Disclaimer: `I'm an idiot`...you are quite modest!!!

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the responses! They're very much appreciated! Now, I'm off to research the difference between parseInt() vs. Number()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May need to use `parseInt` to convert arguments into numbers:

```
this.goalAmount = parseInt(goalAmount);
this.currentStake = parseInt(currentStake);
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the things you want to compare with `parseInt` to convert them to numbers - otherwise they will be compared as strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use the number function:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp

Comment: http://w3fools.com https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: For some reason, when I tried this, it fixed the issue but created an issue when I tried dividing the currentStake by the goalAmount to get a percentage. There was no error, but it was returning unexpected results. When I used the parseInt() function all was copacetic.

Answer (score 0):

Input values are indeed strings, as you suspect. Cast them to numbers:

```
this.goalAmount = Number(goalAmount);
this.currentStake = Number(currentStake);
```

It boils down to this:

```
"9" < "10" // false
Number("9") < Number("10") // true
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
currentGame.play(parseInt(document.getElementById("eCurrentStake").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("eGoalAmount").value));
```